# django-seo set up error - No module named seo

Tags: python, django, seo

I am trying to add [django-seo](https://github.com/willhardy/django-seo) to a test project, but I have an error I don;t know how to solve.

I have followed the [django-seo docs](http://django-seo.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction/index.html):

**1.** I ran pip install DjangoSEO and then confirmed the install with pip freeze;

**2.** I added 'rollyourown.seo' to my installed apps;

**3.** I created a file called seo.py and installed this file alongside my core files: models.py, views.py, forms.py & urls.py. This is the contents of my seo.py file:

```
    from rollyourown import seo

    class MyMetadata(seo.Metadata):
        title = seo.Tag(head=True, max_length=68)
        description = seo.MetaTag(max_length=155)
        keywords = seo.KeywordTag()
        heading = seo.Tag(name="h1")
```

**4.** I added the following code to my urls.py file to set up the admin:

```
    from rollyourown.seo.admin import register_seo_admin
    from django.contrib import admin
    from test_project.seo import MyMetadata

    register_seo_admin(admin.site, MyMetadata)
```

According to the docs, I should now be able to see the django-seo models in the admin, but do not see them.

Instead, I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\test_project\test_project\core\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
from test_project.seo import MyMetadata
ImportError: No module named seo
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: yes I have run syncdb. The problem persists.

Comment: What is your project structure? Your urls.py is under core but you're importing from `test_project`. Does it work with `from .seo import MyMetadata`?

Comment: Leticia, this fixes the issue! Thank you!! If you post this as a response, I will mark it as the correct answer.